# Page with anti-scraping protection in the code?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract information from a web page, when dealing with Xpath helper (chrome extension) it shows the content perfectly, but when taking it to scrapy it returns "None", or "empty":
Web: https://cutt.ly/bjj3ohW
The number --NN are the forms it tested.

[image: Price]

[image: pycharm]

I have tried with Xpath (`//*[@id="da_price"]`,`//*[@id="da_price"]/text()`), `.get('')`, `.extract()`, `.get('').strip()`, Css `#da_price`,`#da_price::text`, Also i used beautifulsoup and scrapy_splas hand returns the result none or empty. I still don't want to try to use selenium because the number of links is quite large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element you're targeting might be dynamically rendered. I tried this and got it to work, I'm targeting the price lower down on the page instead.

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'testspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        return [scrapy.Request(
            url='https://cutt.ly/bjj3ohW',
        )]

    def parse(self, response):
        price = response.css('.price-final > strong::text').get()
        print(price)
```

A good way to test if it's dynamically rendered is to open inspect panel in Chrome `(F12)` and look under the Network tab. Reload the page and look and the first response which should be a `.html` file. Click on that file and then Response. There you can see the html code you can parse in Scrapy. Click `ctrl+F` and search for the CSS selector you're trying to parse.