# I can't extract the links with scrapy

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-shell

i need help for extract the links in the page: [https://www.remax.pt/comprar-empreendimentos?searchQueryState={%22page%22:1,%22sort%22:{%22fieldToSort%22:%22PublishDate%22,%22order%22:1}}](https://www.remax.pt/comprar-empreendimentos?searchQueryState=%7B%22page%22:1,%22sort%22:%7B%22fieldToSort%22:%22PublishDate%22,%22order%22:1%7D%7D)

[image: HTML code]
[image: Results from shell]

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten it, you don't have to target from the top element to your target. It's easier to debug then.

```
response.css('div.developments-search-details-component a::attr(href)').get()
```

You can change this to Xpath if you prefer that. But usually when you try to target an element and it returns null or empty list it's because of a typo or because that element is dynamically rendered after page load.

To debug I'll usually start at a higher element in the tree and see if that exists.
In this case you could try:

```
response.css('div.developments-search-details-component').get()
```

first and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you Felix. I discovered with the element is dynamically rendered in javascript. I dont know how get it

Comment: You can look at the last part of the answer i gave here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65623157/page-with-anti-scraping-protection-in-the-code/65625805#65625805